# Alternatives to Justinmind for mac

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, prototype

For a long time, I have been using Justinmind on my Windows laptop to define complex cases in prototypes using conditions and events. Is there any similar tool for Mac that supports handling of complex conditions? I have done a little research on Invision, Marvel and Sketch but according to my understanding, these tools only support simple interactions. I am attaching a screenshot of Justinmind's events for reference.

[image]

Comment: For what it is worth; we have been using Justinmind on a Mac for a little more than a year. Seems to work ok. We do use simple events that work fine but not anything as complex as your screenshot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it jusr asks for software recommendations